# extract data from html and update mysql data table automatically

Tags: php, mysql, process, upload, extract

Wondering if this is possible. I would like to extract a table from a given URL (HTML) and then have `MySQL` database table updated with the new information. I would like to run this process every 10 minutes automatically without me manually running the process.

Also, I would like `MySQL` server to run this process rather than dedicating my own computer to constantly run this process.

Any ideas? I know `MySQL` doesn't have `xp_cmdshell` so I won't be able to use HTML Agility Pack...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [DOMdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) its most likely faster anyway and then just run it on a cron job/scheduled task.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I looked into it and it led to me finding a solution to my problem.